# How do I use a sentiment analysis model with custom layers trained in Python in tensorflow.js?

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I am pretty new to ML and I want to do some sentiment analysis on Discord messages using discord.js and tensorflow keras.
I started with Python because I only know Python tensorflow, but now I have the problem that I cannot convert my model into a tensorflow.js model. I think the reason for this is that tensorflow.js cannot load custom layers, like Python `tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization()`.

**A sample of my training data csv:**

```
text,sentiment
"piss shit",1
"What a fu#cking airhead this is! This world really is fucked",0
"suck off",0
"I love you so much",1
```

**My model in Python:**

```py
vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
    output_mode="tf_idf"
)
vectorize_layer.adapt(train_x)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(vectorize_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", dtype="float64"))
```

I cannot save the model as a tfjs model because it uses a text_vectorization layer.
I tried to pre-process the data and then use it for training.

**I wrote the following function to do this:**

```py
def __pad_sequence(self, sequences):
    padded_sequences = []
    for seq in sequences:
        if len(seq) > self.metadata["max_len"]:
            seq = seq[-self.metadata["max_len"]:]
        elif len(seq) < self.metadata["max_len"]:
            pad = [0] * (self.metadata["max_len"] - len(seq))
            seq = pad + seq
        padded_sequences.append(seq)
    return padded_sequences

def run(self, data):
    trimmed = re.sub(r"(\.|\,|\!)", "", data.lower()).split(" ")
    sequence = [self.metadata["word_index"]
                .get(_, 2) + self.metadata["index_from"] for _ in trimmed]
    padded_sequence = self.__pad_sequence(self, [sequence])
    input_data = tf.constant(padded_sequence,
                                shape=[1, self.metadata["max_len"]]
                                )

    return input_data
```

**My Node.js pre-processing function:**

```js
function padSequences(sequences, metadata) {
    return sequences.map(seq => {
        if (seq.length > metadata.max_len) {
            seq.splice(0, seq.length - metadata.max_len);
        }
        if (seq.length < metadata.max_len) {
            const pad = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < metadata.max_len - seq.length; ++i) {
                pad.push(0);
            }
            seq = pad.concat(seq);
        }
        return seq;
    });
}

function prepareData(data, metadata) {
    const trimmed = data
        .trim().toLowerCase().replace(/(\.|\,|\!)/g, '').split(' ');
    const sequence = trimmed.map(word => {
        const wordIndex = metadata.word_index[word];
        if (typeof wordIndex === 'undefined') {
            return 2;
        }
        return wordIndex + metadata.index_from;
    });
    const paddedSequence = padSequences([sequence], metadata);

    const input = tf.tensor2d(paddedSequence, [1, metadata.max_len]);

    return input;
    //return paddedSequence;
}
```

**As metadata I use:**
[storage.googleapis.com]
(https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/sentiment_cnn_v1/metadata.json)

My plan was to pre-process the discord.js messages in Node.js and then use them for the model that was trained on the pre-processed data. When I try to train the model with the pre-processed data, I get a very poor accuracy of about 51%, compared to the over 90% that I got with text_vectorization in Python.

**This is what my pre-processed data looks like:**

```py
# "piss shit" looks like this...
[     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0 76508 24635]
```

How can I pre-process my data similar to Python `tf.keras.layers.TextVectorisation()` in tensorflow.js and get about the same results as I get in Python?
`tf.keras.layers.TextVectorisation()` does not seem to be available in tensorflow.js.

Answer (score 0):

I think TensorFlow.js doesn't support custom layers like `TextVectorization` so you'll have to manually preprocess the data in your Node.js application before feeding it to the model. Maybe this will help you:

```js
//Load the metadata from URL
const metadataUrl = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/sentiment_cnn_v1/metadata.json';
const metadata = await fetch(metadataUrl).then((response) => response.json());


//Preprocess the text messages
const sequence = trimmed.map((word) => {
  const index = metadata['word_index'][word];
  return index !== undefined ? index + metadata['index_from'] : 2; // 2 represents the out-of-vocabulary (OOV) token
});

const paddedSequence = sequence.slice(-metadata['max_len']).concat(Array.from({ length: metadata['max_len'] - sequence.length }).fill(0));

const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d([paddedSequence], [1, metadata['max_len']]);
```

**Edit**

You can use the `natural` package, which provides various NLP functionalities to create a function in Node.js that performs text vectorization similar to `tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization()` but in Python TensorFlow library...

```js
const natural = require('natural');

function textVectorization(texts) {
  const vectorizer = new natural.TfidfVectorizer();
  const vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(texts);

  return vectors.to2DArray();
}

// Example usage
const texts = [
  'This is the first document.',
  'This document is the second document.',
  'And this is the third one.',
  'Is this the first document?'
];

const vectorizedTexts = textVectorization(texts);
console.log(vectorizedTexts);
```

I didn't tested this but it uses the `TfidfVectorizer` from the natural package to perform the vectorization. The function first initializes the vectorizer, then fits the vectorizer to the input texts using the `fit_transform` method, and finally converts the resulting vectors to a 2D array using the `to2DArray` method.

Comment: I tried to do that, as I wrote in my question. I will add my Node.js pre-process Code to my question. Doing this destroyed my accuracy, and I don't know why.

Comment: I get what you want. I'll update my answer. I'm hoping that will help you.

Comment: I will try it as soon as I have time, I will accept your answer later if it solves my problem. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the natural package does not seem to include the natural.TfidfVectorizer() method. I tried to find the method in the docs, but I could not find it there either.